# Is it possible to add more than one child to the safearea widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

body: SafeArea(
child: Row(
children: [
Container(
height: double.infinity,
color: Colors.red,
width: 64.0,
),
Container(
height: double.infinity,
width: 64.0,
),
],
),
),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, instead of using `Container()` you can use `Column()`

```
Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child:Text('Child 1',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),
              Container(
                child:Text('Child 2',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Layouts in flutter:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout